# Java/SPNEGO: Unwanted SPN canonicalization?

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, spnego, spn

I'm currently trying to implement a Java client to an SPNEGO protected web service using the [SPNEGO library](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) from SourceForge (the server is using the same library). I can not get it to authenticate successfully, my requests always end up as

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
```

This is similar to the symptoms that I get when accessing the web service from a browser with an inappropriate hostname, and indeed some debugging in Wireshark reveals that the client sends a wrong SPN with the request - I send to `service-test.client.com`, which is registered as an SPN and has an `A` record in DNS, but is registered in the Windows domain as `server-1234.client.corp`. Even though I send my request to `http://service-test.client.com` (see matching `Host` header), the SPN that Java requests a ticket for is the "internal" Windows name:

[image: Wireshark decode of the HTTP request]

The same sent from Chrome or IE has matching `Host` headers and SPNs:

[image]

Since there is none of this translation occurs in my code or the SPNEGO library, I presume it must be happening somehwere in the JRE. I've been looking into the JGSS source, but it's a bit hard to understand. Can anyone tell me how to skip this translation and get tickets for the correct SPN?

Client code:

```
SpnegoHttpURLConnection con = new SpnegoHttpURLConnection("spnego-client", user, password);
con.connect(new URL("http://service-test.client.com:8083/service"));
int rc = con.getResponseCode();
String msg = con.getResponseMessage();
```

Comment: Recheck your DNS. Do a reverse lookup. Most problems occur from incorrect reverse DNS entries. What is the name of your realm? Page 85 in this [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2743.txt) might help you. Windows uses SSPI which does actually the same thing as GSS-API but in a diffrent fashion. Just another hint: You need to provide information about the KDC serving the `CLIENT.COM` realm otherwise Java won't be able to obtain a ticket.

We have a similar constellation at work. This is deemed to fail because the realm `CLIENT.COM` is not known to Kerberos.

Comment: You can sniff the KDC traffic with Wireshark too. Filter for `kerberos`.

Comment: @Michael-O: thanks, great comments. If I read that RFC correctly, it shouldn't do any reverse-lookup shenanigans, though... I'll verify on Monday what DNS/Kerberos traffic happens...

Comment: Actually not, it says "When a reference to a name of this type is resolved, the "hostname" may (as an example implementation strategy) be canonicalized by attempting a DNS lookup and using the fully-qualified domain name which is returned, or by using the "hostname" as provided if the DNS lookup fails." So it depends. It's perfectly natural that a reverse lookup is done. This is how Kerberos verifies the hostname. This is actually crucial if you are running DNS round-robin. Without that it won't never be able to construct the real SPN. Tell me your results on monday. I am excited.

Comment: Thanks - that's all very plausible, but I don't get why IE would behave differently from Java here. I always assumed a round-robin setup would have to run with a shared SPN. 

If it works the way you describe, I'm in trouble because we use multiple SPNs bound to different services on the same machine/IP address - "Kerberos virtual hosting" if you will. So far, with just browser clients, it worked, but I might really just have got lucky.

Comment: Well, let me clear up some things: 1. You cannot share SPN, an SPN exists once and only once in the entire forest. Each host needs a distinct/fully-qualified SPN. There cannot be a round-robin SPN. 2. Multihoming/virtual hosting is not suitable for kerberos actually because it was invented way after Kerberos. Always use distinct IPs for distinct services. Consult [this](http://www.cmf.nrl.navy.mil/CCS/people/kenh/kerberos-faq.html#multihomed) to avoid serious problems. Kerberos is very serious about a badly configured DNS.

Comment: I usually use JGSS, GSS-API (HEimdal/MIT) and SSPI with a huge forest with hundreds of domains with thousands of DCs. It all runs well with cross-domain as long as DNS is properly configured and your krb5.conf is correct.

Comment: @Michael-O: I've verified that Java 6 behaves exactly as you suggest, i.e. doing a DNS fwd lookup, then a reverse DNS lookup. I'm also inclined to believe your reading of the RFC there. The fun thing is that with further testing I've established that Java 6 does it like that, while Java 7 doesn't...

Comment: The behavior of Java 6 is correct. As your win admin for a correction of entries. If you think that there is a bug in Java 7's JGSS, you should open a ticket with Oracle. Make sure that it really does not perform a DNS lookup (Wireshark, correct krb5.conf, etc.). You can check the source of the OpenJDK and ask the security-dev mailing list of the OpenJDK. I haven't tried JDK 7 here, we are still on JDK 6. What does Java 7 do?

Comment: Java 7 (post-u4, since there was bug 7089889 before, which broke my Kerberos applications anyway) does what I'd expect, it requests a ticket for HTTP/service-test.client.com. 

Relevant diff chunk from OpenJDK sources: http://pastie.org/4656129

Re: correctness, I suppose both are correct, at least according to your RFC quote that says the implementation "may" do the DNS canonicalization.

Comment: Check [RFC3120](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt) and search for "canon". It seems like GSS-API impls may canonicalize but Kerberos should not do so. If you like I could test JDK 7/MIT Kerberos and Heimdal against our round-robin servers. I am curious how this change is supposed to work. Either way you should work this out with your admin. Because GSS-API is the code on top and Kerberos just a mechanism.

Comment: @Michael-O: I'd be interested to hear how your setup would deal with the Java 7 behaviour... My problem with changing the reverse DNS is that there are already other kerberized services (IIS with SPNEGO authentication) on that machine, running under a different account and using a different SPN, so that changing the reverse DNS would likely then break their service. For now, I'll just consider this bullet dodged and upgrade to Java 7. Thanks for the help, that really helped me figure out what was happening - if you want to cast your comments into answer form, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Yes, I will transform my comments as an anwser. The test setup will follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary from the comments above:

Recheck your DNS. Do a reverse lookup. Most problems occur from incorrect reverse DNS entries.

Page 85 in [RFC2713](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2743.txt) might help you and check [RFC4120](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt) and search for "canon".

When a SPN for a host-based service is constructed with GSS-API you have to canonicalize that name with the target mechanism. The RFC says

> When a reference to a name of this type is resolved, the "hostname" may (as an example implementation strategy) be canonicalized by attempting a DNS lookup and using the fully-qualified domain name which is returned, or by using the "hostname" as provided if the DNS
>      lookup fails.  The canonicalization operation also maps the host's name into lower-case characters.

Where the Kerberos 5 RFC says:

> server and when transmitted.  Thus, for example, one should not rely  on an unprotected DNS record to map a host alias to the primary name
>      of a server, accepting the primary name as the party that one intends
>      to contact, since an attacker can modify the mapping and impersonate
>      the party.
>
> Implementations of Kerberos and protocols based on Kerberos MUST NOT
>      use insecure DNS queries to canonicalize the hostname components of
>      the service principal names (i.e., they MUST NOT use insecure DNS
>      queries to map one name to another to determine the host part of the
>      principal name with which one is to communicate).  In an environment
>      without secure name service, application authors MAY append a
>      statically configured domain name to unqualified hostnames before
>      passing the name to the security mechanisms, but they should do no
>      more than that.  Secure name service facilities, if available, might
>      be trusted for hostname canonicalization, but such canonicalization
>      by the client SHOULD NOT be required by KDC implementations.
>
> Implementation note: Many current implementations do some degree of
>      canonicalization of the provided service name, often using DNS even
>      though it creates security problems.  However, there is no
>      consistency among implementations as to whether the service name is
>      case folded to lowercase or whether reverse resolution is used.  To
>      maximize interoperability and security, applications SHOULD provide
>      security mechanisms with names that result from folding the user-
>      entered name to lowercase without performing any other modifications
>      or canonicalization.

It seems like GSS-API impls may canonicalize but Kerberos should not do so if the DNS is untrusted.
So it depends. It's perfectly natural that a reverse lookup is done. This is how Kerberos verifies the hostname. This is actually crucial if you are running DNS round-robin. Without that it won't never be able to construct the real SPN.

Though I would really as this on a Kerberos mailing list. This is a very interesting point.

I have checked the MIT Kerberos implementation and there is the method [`krb5_sname_to_principal`](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/krb_appldev/refs/api/krb5_sname_to_principal.html) which actually does this if you check the source code in `sn2princ.c`:

```
if (type == KRB5_NT_SRV_HST) {
        struct addrinfo *ai = NULL, hints;
        int err;
        char hnamebuf[NI_MAXHOST];

        /* Note that the old code would accept numeric addresses,
           and if the gethostbyaddr step could convert them to
           real hostnames, you could actually get reasonable
           results.  If the mapping failed, you'd get dotted
           triples as realm names.  *sigh*

           The latter has been fixed in hst_realm.c, but we should
           keep supporting numeric addresses if they do have
           hostnames associated.  */

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
        err = getaddrinfo(hostname, 0, &hints, &ai);
        if (err) {
#ifdef DEBUG_REFERRALS
            printf("sname_to_princ: failed to canonicalize %s; using as-is", hostname);
#endif
        }
        remote_host = strdup((ai && ai->ai_canonname) ? ai->ai_canonname : hostname);
        if (!remote_host) {
            if(ai)
                freeaddrinfo(ai);
            return ENOMEM;
        }

        if ((!err) && maybe_use_reverse_dns(context, DEFAULT_RDNS_LOOKUP)) {
            /*
             * Do a reverse resolution to get the full name, just in
             * case there's some funny business going on.  If there
             * isn't an in-addr record, give up.
             */
            /* XXX: This is *so* bogus.  There are several cases where
               this won't get us the canonical name of the host, but
               this is what we've trained people to expect.  We'll
               probably fix it at some point, but let's try to
               preserve the current behavior and only shake things up
               once when it comes time to fix this lossage.  */
            err = getnameinfo(ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen,
                              hnamebuf, sizeof(hnamebuf), 0, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);
            freeaddrinfo(ai);
            if (err == 0) {
                free(remote_host);
                remote_host = strdup(hnamebuf);
                if (!remote_host)
                    return ENOMEM;
            }
        } else
            freeaddrinfo(ai);
    }
```

So, I guess we have to ask with the mailing list.

Comment: I have created a [thread](http://mailman.mit.edu/pipermail/kerberos/2012-September/018372.html) on the MIT Kerberos mailing list for that.